# Unable to start MySql as a service on a wnidows 7 machine

Tags: mysql

I am new to MYsql and have downloaded mysql-installer-community-5.6.14.0 and tried to install.
    But this process stopped at the configuration step. I tried googling for 2 days but was unable to find the solution. I have made mysql as a windows service to run as local system service and when i try to start it the following error comes in pc.err file

```
2013-10-20 09:28:40 3312 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
2013-10-20 09:28:40 3312 [Warning] option 'innodb-autoextend-increment': unsigned value 67108864 adjusted to 1000
2013-10-20 09:28:40 1974 InnoDB: Warning: Using innodb_additional_mem_pool_size is DEPRECATED. This option may be removed in future releases, together with the option innodb_use_sys_malloc and with the InnoDB's internal memory allocator.
2013-10-20 09:28:40 3312 [Note] InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
2013-10-20 09:28:40 3312 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use Windows interlocked functions
2013-10-20 09:28:40 3312 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.3
2013-10-20 09:28:40 3312 [Note] InnoDB: Not using CPU crc32 instructions
2013-10-20 09:28:40 3312 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 200.0M
2013-10-20 09:28:40 3312 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2013-10-20 09:28:40 3312 [Note] InnoDB: Highest supported file format is Barracuda.
2013-10-20 09:28:41 3312 [Note] InnoDB: 128 rollback segment(s) are active.
2013-10-20 09:28:41 3312 [Note] InnoDB: Waiting for purge to start
2013-10-20 09:28:41 3312 [Note] InnoDB: 5.6.14 started; log sequence number 1626017
2013-10-20 09:28:41 3312 [Note] Server hostname (bind-address): '*'; port: 3306
2013-10-20 09:28:41 3312 [Note] IPv6 is available.
2013-10-20 09:28:41 3312 [Note]   - '::' resolves to '::';
2013-10-20 09:28:41 3312 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '::'.
**2013-10-20 09:28:41 3312 [ERROR] Can't start server: listen() on TCP/IP port: No such file or directory
2013-10-20 09:28:41 3312 [ERROR] listen() on TCP/IP failed with error 0
2013-10-20 09:28:41 3312 [ERROR] Aborting**
Please help as I am a newbie am not able to get anything.
Thanks in advance
Raghu dev
```

Comment: `C:\>netstat -a -n | findstr 3306` returns what, on your system?

Comment: Hi it's not returning anything

Comment: It looks like MySQL is having trouble when trying to listen on port 3306 (windows returns the nonsensical "no such file or directory"), but that command not returning anything suggests that the problem is not due to a conflict on that port, which seemed like a likely candidate.  Is there a `bind-address` in your my.ini file?  Are you intending to use ipv4 or ipv6?

Comment: There is no bind address in my.ini file .. in the error file it shows ipv6 is available

Comment: `bind-address = 0.0.0.0` should (?) force the server to only try binding to the ipv4 stack, so that would be my next suggestion.

Comment: Hi i have added the bind-address and did the following C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.6\bin> mysqld --install MySQL561 --defaults-file="C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.6\my.ini"
Service successfully installed.

C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.6\bin>net start MySQL561
The MySQL561 service is starting...
The MySQL561 service could not be started.

A system error has occurred.

System error 1067 has occurred.

The process terminated unexpectedly.

Comment: Anything new in the mysql error log?

Comment: hi michael adding mysqld to firewall solved the issue . Thanks for sparing ur time..

Answer (score 4):

Open command prompt and type **"netstat -an**" without the quotes.

You can view the list of ports that are open. If the port 3306 is used by some other process, then modify the port in **my.ini** to port **3307** or some other port which no other sservice is using and restart the **MySQL** service, it should pick up the change.