# Issue when running mysqld

Tags: mysql

I download `mysql-5.7.9-winx64.zip` and when i try to run `mysqld` i got this error :

```
E:\Softwares\mysql-5.7.9-winx64\bin>mysqld
mysqld: Could not create or access the registry key needed for the MySQL application
to log to the Windows EventLog. Run the application with sufficient
privileges once to create the key, add the key manually, or turn off
logging for that application.
mysqld: Can't change dir to 'E:\Softwares\mysql-5.7.9-winx64\data\' (Errcode: 2 - No such file or directory)
2015-11-13T10:45:09.715411Z 0 [Warning] TIMESTAMP with implicit DEFAULT value is deprecated. Please use --explicit_defaults_for_ti
mestamp server option (see documentation for more details).
2015-11-13T10:45:09.731411Z 0 [Warning] Insecure configuration for --secure-file-priv: Current value does not restrict location of
 generated files. Consider setting it to a valid, non-empty path.
2015-11-13T10:45:09.732411Z 0 [ERROR] Cannot open Windows EventLog; check privileges, or start server with --log_syslog=0
2015-11-13T10:45:09.732411Z 0 [Note] mysqld (mysqld 5.7.9) starting as process 3532 ...
2015-11-13T10:45:09.864419Z 0 [Warning] Can't create test file E:\Softwares\mysql-5.7.9-winx64\data\yous-PC.lower-test
2015-11-13T10:45:09.864419Z 0 [Warning] Can't create test file E:\Softwares\mysql-5.7.9-winx64\data\yous-PC.lower-test
2015-11-13T10:45:09.864419Z 0 [ERROR] failed to set datadir to E:\Softwares\mysql-5.7.9-winx64\data\
2015-11-13T10:45:09.865419Z 0 [ERROR] Aborting

2015-11-13T10:45:09.865419Z 0 [Note] Binlog end
2015-11-13T10:45:09.945424Z 0 [Note] mysqld: Shutdown complete
```

Comment: Since the error seems to be related to privileges/permissions, have you tried to "run as administrator"? I'm not too savvy about permissions on Windows machines...but I think "run as administrator" is similar to a linux command running under `sudo`.

Comment: In addition, the errors mention not being able to locate a certain folder (looks like your database data folder): `'E:\Softwares\mysql-5.7.9-winx64\data\'`. Does this folder exist?

Comment: Please consider each of the warming/error messages that you have provided - there is lots of information within the messages.

Comment: Im not in work but i think i try to run it as administrator without success and the file don't exit.

Comment: Create "data" folder in the base folder and it will work

Answer (score 8, accepted):

try the MySQL Installer 5.7.9 to install it automatically mysql-installer-web-community-5.7.9.0.msi and it works.

Answer (score 10):

For development/debugging purposes i need a MySQL-Server without installation and don't want it to change my windows installation, e.g. by setting registry keys. MySQL's hint "start server with --log_syslog=0" works well:

```
mysqld -u root --log_syslog=0
```

Answer (score 9):

You must run the Command Prompt as administrator.  Then run mysqld.

To do this right click the Command Prompt startup icon and then select Run As Admininistrator.  Then run mysqld and you should no longer see that error.

mysqld needs access to your registry the first time. you do not have to do this after the first time.

Comment: exactly the same ? or some change ? (It may be the folder create only that fail after that)

Comment: Run as administrator should work. I had this problem and went away as soon as I started command prompt 'Run as Administrator'

Comment: @Blag for me it was indeed `Errcode: 2 - No such file or directory`, so I created the directory mentioned in this error and `mysqld` started working. However the server did not start due to `Can't start server: Bind on TCP/IP port: No such file or directory`, so I changed the [port from 3306 to 3307 in _my.ini_](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19473966/6225838) and finally got it working.

Answer (score 2):

Windows operating system will not allow you to make changes in certain system critical registry keys. Nevertheless, if you want to make changes even in such registry keys, you will have to take full control of these keys before Windows will allow you to make or save the changes.

check this link:
http://www.thewindowsclub.com/how-to-take-full-control-of-windows-7-registry-keys

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the same problem on a Windows machine. I tried to "Run as Administrator" and change the path, but nothing prevailed.

It turned out Mysql wasn't reading the "my.ini" file. 
I solved the problem by putting the "my.ini" file into the C:/Windows directory as it was pointed out in the official MySQL troubleshoot guide [HERE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/windows-troubleshooting.html)

Answer (score 0):

I run into both log error and data folder misconfig issues like you have.

Here is my solution:

- Run the Command Prompt as administrator. Then run mysqld.  - (just like user1660791 suggested)
- For the path error, you need to make sure to \ instead of \ for path. 
  Example as below:
  `basedir = C:\\myfolder\\mysql-5.7.11-winx64`

Have to post this as new answer due to i don't have permission comment of others post.

Answer (score 0):

Use `basedir = C:/myfolder/mysql-5.7.11-winx64` then find `cmd.exe` for the path: `C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe`.

In order to do this, right click the Command Prompt startup icon and then select "Run As Admininistrator".

Comment: in my case, only is necessary run as admin the FIRST TIME, then AFTER, i can run as any user. (user NO ADMIN, no privileges specials).